# XSLT to deep sort any generic XML on element names

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I was wondering if it's possible to deep sort an XML (with attributes) on element names without knowing the structure of the XML or the element names. The sorting should be only based on XML Elements and not the attributes. Thanks

Example XML:

```
 <Customer>
    <CustomerID>ALFKI</CustomerID>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>10692</OrderID>
      <CustomerID>ALFKI</CustomerID>
      <OrderDate>1997-10-03</OrderDate>
    </Order>
    <CompanyName>Alfreds Futterkiste</CompanyName>
  </Customer>
```

Result Expected:

```
 <Customer>
    <CompanyName>Alfreds Futterkiste</CompanyName>
    <CustomerID>ALFKI</CustomerID>
    <Order>
      <CustomerID>ALFKI</CustomerID>
      <OrderDate>1997-10-03</OrderDate>
      <OrderID>10692</OrderID>
    </Order>
  </Customer>
```

Update: Actual XML

```
<NAB>
    <jcr:content>
        <par>
            <color>
                <title>
                    <![CDATA[Rouge sangria]]>
                </title>
                <code>
                    <![CDATA[NAB]]>
                </code>
                <image_url>
                    <![CDATA[/assets/2016/x6/colors/exterior/nab.jpg]]>
                </image_url>
            </color>
        </par>
    </jcr:content>
</NAB>
```

**UPDATE:**

I just found out that sorting a specific section of XML (under an element/tag `<Handling>`) screws up things. Is it possible to modify the XSLT to avoid everything under (all the children of) `<Handling>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the following stylesheet, which sorts child elements before applying templates to them?

Start with an *identity template* and add a template that matches elements that themselves have child elements:

```
<xsl:template match="*[*]">
```

Copy those elements to the output and apply templates to their content - but before, sort them by their name.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[*]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Customer>
   <CompanyName>Alfreds Futterkiste</CompanyName>
   <CustomerID>ALFKI</CustomerID>
   <Order>
      <CustomerID>ALFKI</CustomerID>
      <OrderDate>1997-10-03</OrderDate>
      <OrderID>10692</OrderID>
   </Order>
</Customer>
```

---

Please note: This solution might not give the correct result in all contexts, for instance when there are namespaces in the document. If there are prefixed element names in your document, you would have to sort by `local-name()`:

```
<xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
```

Try this solution online [here](http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3M/1) and an example with a namespace [here](http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3M).

---

**EDIT**: So far, my solution did not work for attributes of elements whose child elements are sorted. Use this suggestion by Daniel Haley to keep attributes if there are any:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
   <xsl:sort select="self::*/local-name()"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

with an explicit `select` attribute on `xsl:apply-templates`.

---

**EDIT 2**

> I just figured out that sorting out a certain part of XML under a specific element screws up things. Will it be possible to modify the above code to omit sorting under `<Handling>` element tag?

Change the second template to

```
<xsl:template match="*[* and not(self::Handling or ancestor::Handling)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

to avoid sorting the children of the `Handling` element. It does not sort the children of the descendant elements of `Handling` either. If that's not what you intended to do, change the template match to

```
<xsl:template match="*[* and not(self::Handling)]">
```

to only avoid sorting the immediate children of `Handling`.

Please note: if `Handling` is in a namespace, the approach above will not work.

Comment: Trying it out. Thanks

Comment: @BrownTownCoder You are welcome. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Funny thing. This should work, but I am getting another error on my xml. "The prefix "jcr" for element "jcr:content" is not bound." jcr:content is one of the element in my xml. Any idea what this can be?

Comment: @BrownTownCoder Yes, it is an error in your input document, not in your XSLT code. In there, you have an element named `jcr:content` and you have not _declared_ this namespace like so: `xmlns:jcr="http://www.example.com""`.

Comment: @BrownTownCoder Most likely, the content element needs to be: `<jcr:content xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0">` or similar. The `jcr` prefix can be associated with any namespace URI to make your document well-formed, but `jcr:` seems to be a conventional prefix.

Comment: Got it. Perfect. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: This will drop any attributes that are on elements that contain elements. Probably not a big deal since the OP has posted his actual XML and it doesn't contain any attributes, but he/she did mention attributes in the question. Here's a modified version of your first solution that will handle the attrs: http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3M/2

Comment: @DanielHaley Thanks for pointing this out, you are right of course. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I just figured out that sorting out a certain part of XML under a specific element screws up things. Will it be possible to modify the above code to omit sorting under <Handling> element tag? Thanks

Comment: @BrownTownCoder See my second edit to the answer. This is the last edit I am making to my answer - if you have more questions after that, please start a new post. And if you do, make sure you show a **representative** example of your XML input right away - including namespaces, if there are any.