# Omit certain portion of XML tree while Sorting using XSLT

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I am sorting a large XML file using the following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

The issue is, I want to Omit certain subtree of the XML. I am not sure how I can achieve that. For example, lets say my  original XML is

```
<Car>
    <Handling>
        <Suspension>
            <Type>Coilover</Type>
            <Brand>Ohlins</Brand>
        </Suspension>
        <Steering>
            <Type>Electric</Type>
            <Brand>Momo</Brand>
        </Steering>
    </Handling>
    <Engine>
        <Hybrid>
            <Type>LiON</Type>
            <Brand>Duracell</Brand>
        </Hybrid>
        <Combustion>
            <Type>Rotary</Type>
            <Brand>Mazda</Brand>
        </Combustion>
    </Engine>
</Car>
```

The output should be like below. Notice that everything under `<Handling>` is not Sorted

```
<Car>
    <Engine>
        <Combustion>
            <Brand>Mazda</Brand>
            <Type>Rotary</Type>
        </Combustion>
        <Hybrid>
            <Brand>Duracell</Brand>
            <Type>LiON</Type>
        </Hybrid>
    </Engine>
    <Handling>
        <Suspension>
            <Type>Coilover</Type>
            <Brand>Ohlins</Brand>
        </Suspension>
        <Steering>
            <Type>Electric</Type>
            <Brand>Momo</Brand>
        </Steering>
    </Handling>
</Car>
```

Any idea how to achieve this by modifying the XSLT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two templates in your stylesheet, one which just copies the context node, and one which copies the context node and sorts its child elements.

To exclude certain elements from the sorting mechanism, you need to exclude them from being processed by the second template. A possible (quick hack) solution is to add another template to match `Handling` and all its descendants and do a normal copy:

```
<xsl:template match="Handling|Handling//*" priority="2">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The "hackish" thing about it is that you explicitly set a high priority. It is probably better to modify the existing sorting template to `<xsl:template match="*[* and not(self::Handling or ancestor::Handling)]">` as I have already told the OP [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35491574/1987598).